# Return Whole Match instead of capturing group (REGEXP BIG QUERY)

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am new in regular expressions and big query and I want to extract the age range from a string to define it as a variable in a table, so I did something like this:

```sql
WITH example AS (
SELECT
"Bgfks Falda Tutú De Tul De 5 Capas Para Niñas Con Moño Para El Pelo, Falda Tutú Para Niños - 8-15 Years Old - Rosado" AS name
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(name),r"[0-9]{1,2}( - | a | to |-|a|to)[0-9]{1,2}") as AGE_RANGE FROM example
```

There are multiple groups ( - | a | to |-|a|to) because these are the patterns that can be present in data "1-10", "1 - 10", "1 to 10", "1to10",...

But this just returns the capturing group "-" and what I want is to have "8-15". Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

I check the regular expression in a page and I think what I am getting back is the "Group 1" and what I want is the "Match 1"

[image: Test]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a non-capturing group. BigQuery uses `re2` regex syntax, and non-capturing group is represented by `(?:re)`:

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(name),r"[0-9]{1,2}(?: - | a | to |-|a|to)[0-9]{1,2}")
```

Output:

[image]

Docs: [re2 Syntax reference](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below

REGEXP_EXTRACT(name, r'(?i)\d+ ?(?:-|a|to) ?\d+')

Answer (score 0):

In case if your goal is to extract age range from text - you can use below approach with use of [ML.GENERATE_TEXT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-generate-text) function which lets you perform generative natural language tasks on text that's stored in BigQuery tables by using the Vertex AI text-bison natural language foundation model

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION EXTRACT_AGE(text STRING) AS ((
SELECT TRIM(STRING(ml_generate_text_result['predictions'][0]['content']), '" ')
  FROM ML.GENERATE_TEXT(MODEL `your_project.your_dataset.your_model_llm`,
  (SELECT FORMAT('Extract age range from following text - %s. Return ONLY range in form of start age-end age', text)  AS prompt)
)));
SELECT name, EXTRACT_AGE(name) AS AGE_RANGE
FROM your_table
```

if applied to sample data as below

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION EXTRACT_AGE(text STRING) AS ((
SELECT TRIM(STRING(ml_generate_text_result['predictions'][0]['content']), '" ')
  FROM ML.GENERATE_TEXT(MODEL `your_project.your_dataset.your_model_llm`,
  (SELECT FORMAT('Extract age range from following text - %s. Return ONLY range in form of start age-end age', text)  AS prompt)
)));
WITH example AS (
  SELECT "Falda Tutú Para Niños - 8-15 Years Old - Rosado" AS name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Falda Tutú Para Niños - 8 - 15 Years Old - Rosado" AS name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Falda Tutú Para Niños - 8 to 15 Years Old - Rosado" AS name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Falda Tutú Para Niños - 8TO15 Years Old - Rosado" AS name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Falda Tutú Para Niños - 8a15 Years Old - Rosado" AS name
)
SELECT name, EXTRACT_AGE(name) AS AGE_RANGE
FROM example
```

with output

[image]